# discord.js : reaction.message.author.tag is sending user who reacted not message author

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the user tag of the author of the message that was reacted to, and the user who reacted. However, in the console it just shows the person who reacted for both of them, even though they are different. I need to get the author of the message too, can someone tell me what I did wrong? Here's my code:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Message Author: ${reaction.message.author.tag}`)
    console.log(`User who reacted: ${user.tag}`)
})
```

Comment: I don’t think this is your problem, but try caching the reaction with `reaction.fetch()` and also cache the message with `reaction.message.fetch()`. But like I said, I don’t think is your problem

Comment: I tried it, but it's still showing the same user for both, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely not a problem on your side.
According to [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) it should return the message author.